# Wcf webservice execution timeout

Tags: wcf

How can I increase timeout for the wcf web service operation as my wcf service may take more than 5-10 hours to execute function and update inside database?

Answer (score 0):

Redesign your WCF service so that instead of providing a service operation spanning the entire 5-10 hour process, it exposes an operation which starts the long-running process asynchronously and then returns immediately.

You can add further service operations to check the status of the long running process, or cancel it, etc.